# microsoftgraph nodejs basic example

Tags: node.js, microsoft-graph-api

I have installed the basic nodejs rest example (nodejs-connect-rest-sample-master) and got it running. My problem is that I do not really understand how the components interact - and I am not particularly speaking about the Microsoft Graph part. I understand that the HBS-Files are providing the HTML part, but I do not get which JS-Files react on them. (I have a rather simplistic background, using html to provide the layout and then using a Javascript called in the HMTL header to react on Events).

Can anyone point to an explanation?

Answer (score 0):

This is an Express application that uses Passport for authentication with `passport-azure-ad` for authentication strategy, `express-session` to manage sessions, `cookie-parser` for cookies, `body-parser` for JSON body handling, and Morgan for logging.

See the following documentation for details:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/express
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser
- https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/passport-azure-ad
- https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan

An explanation of how it all works together is here:

- https://github.com/microsoftgraph/nodejs-connect-rest-sample#readme